# Working with address data extracted from *.osm

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

My goal is get all the addresses from a certain country, ideally - from all countries, but for now - only from one.

I downloaded an *.osm file from here http://download.geofabrik.de/ for a certain territory which contained a few countries and extracted the data from that file using Osm2pgsql to a Postgres database. There were no errors, all went well.

But now I can't get along with those tables in the db, I can't figure out how actually to **query all the addresses** from a country I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the first thing to do is to import your data again after you have read about addresses in OSM from http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Addresses.

Why you should do import again is that the default osm2pgsql style file does not import all the keys which will likely need, for example addr:street 
https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/default.style

Oncy you have imported data with the tags you want to have you can find addresses from osm_points table with

`select * from osm_points where addr:housenumber is not null or addr:street is not null`.

You can make the query better. More important, however, is to notice that the OSM addresses are very often given for the building polygons. Compare 28 million addresses on nodes and 14 million addressed on ways and relations in http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/addr%3Ahousenumber. That means that you must run the same address queries also from the osm_polygons table. If you want to get a unified address data you can convert buildings into points with

`select ST_Centroid(way) as way from osm polygons where...`.

Here is something to start with. Consider still if you want to invent everything yourself or if you would rather use some ready made tool like Nominatim http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim.

Comment: `Why you should do import again is that the default osm2pgsql style file does not import all the keys which will likely need, for example addr:street` - yes, but there's no mention about ":street" tag there.

Comment: If you want it add `node,way addr:street text linear` into styles. It is up to you to take it or leave it, this tag is not always added to addresses.

Comment: how do I re-create the db easily, just delete 4 tables (planet_osm_point, planet_osm_line, planet_osm_roads, planet_osm_polygon) and run osm2pgsql again? How about views, functions?

Comment: Run osm2pgsql again, it should drop automatically old tables.

Comment: how about the country, what column stands for it? because osm file contains more than one country.

Comment: None. You must search countries with spatial queries. OSM does contain administrational borders but they are not as polygons. You will find it tricky.

Comment: I tried this select * from planet_osm_point where ("addr:housenumber" is not null or "addr:street" is not null) and "addr:country" = 'UK', it did give me the result but less than 100 records.

Comment: You can't rely on addr:country. I said it will be tricky.

Comment: how would I search countries "with spatial queries. "? What's that?

Comment: I mean to select all addresses which are inside the polygon that defines the borders of UK in your case. You do not have the polygon yet but once you have you can do a query by using the PostGIS function ST_Intersects http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html. Something to read about spatial relationships is for example in http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/spatial_relationships.htm and in http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reference.html#Spatial_Relationships_Measurements

Comment: I can dig it. But how do I get that polygon (which defines the borders of the UK)?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know really. You can spend a week by reading how to resolve administrative boundaries from OSM data. What you are interested in is this relation http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/62149. Naturalearthdata.com has some public domain data but I do not know if the accuracy is good for you. OS Open data may have borders I have never checked. But this begins to be all too deep for a single Stackexchange question. Perhaps  https://help.openstreetmap.org/ serves you better than I.

Comment: If the boundary is in relation 62149, the polygon with osm_id -62149 should be the equivalent. Or take the Geofabrik Great Britain extract which contains only UK data.

Comment: Or you can get a shapefile or other geometry from somewhere with only UK polygon and do the `ST_Intersects`

Answer (score 1):

You most probably don't want to invent your own geocoder because this is a really tricky task. [Addresses in OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Addresses) are rarely stored as a full, complete set for every single object. Instead, pre-calculations have to be done in order to add administrative information like cities, municipalities, countries and so on.

Instead try to use one of the already [available geocoders for OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines), for example [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) which currently powers the search on openstreetmap.org.